# Images not appearing in Joomla template

Tags: css, image, joomla

I'm new to Joomla, but I've followed few tutorials. I've created a template for my website, but no images are showing up. Looking to the source, my image references look like:

```
<img src="/templates/fiziaimages/zdjecieDol.png" />
```

When they should be looking like:

```
<img src="/templates/fizia/images/zdjecieDol.png" />
                          ^
```

`fizia/images` is  the correct directory, so I don't know what causes the backslash to not appear.

Comment: Have you added your image in site XML file like <filename>zdjecieDol.png</filename> ?

Answer (score 0):

in a first time you can use your browser inspector to verify if your images are really found.

If it's ok you can try to put your images in the "image" directory in the root of your website